# Best approach to dual boot and clone HP Pavillion

Tags: ubuntu, ssd

I just received a HP Pavillion HPE 8xt Desktop w/i7, 16G ram, and 1T hard drive/Win 7.
My goal is to 
1) Set up a Dual Boot to Ubuntu 
2) Transfer the booting capability to a Plextor Sata3 120G SSD.

As I understand it, the HP IBISB Chigaco MB was only set up to support Sata S2, but I bought the Sata3 as it is not much more price wise than a S2 and it would at least be the latest state of the art in a future computer.  Also, I understand it is backward compatible, but only that I will be limited to the 3G/s bottleneck. Any thoughts are welcome here.

I'm wondering if I should set up the dual boot to ubununtu 1st and then clone next to the SSD. Or would it make more sense to clone to SSD 1st (w/windows), then set up dual boot only on the SSD; using 1st drive as more of a data storage device.  Also, any pointers to related examples would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably split this into several questions, as you ask about different and only marginally related things. A good indication is that half your question is is unrelated to the title. A link or two to the products you describe would likely help too.

Comment: I don't know that you'll gather any more information than I already outlined. But the HP Pavillion HPE page is here:     http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/pavilion-hpe/highlights.html         Plextor drive is here.  http://www.amazon.com/Plextor-PX-128M3S-2-5-Inch-Solid-State/dp/B006I38EJ2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1333007432&sr=8-1  I suppose the main question is for those familiar with HP builds (with a disk drive) and want to use dual boot ubuntu with both transferred to a SSD, what is the best experienced based approach.

Comment: Admittedly, I've never used HP's web pages before, but when I google "HP IBISB Chigaco" I get this question and a training facility, and google suggests some hotels. I eventually found a half-baked spec for the machine [here](http://bit.ly/HhTNm7), but no mention of the mainboard or SATA controller at all. It did not show up as a configuration option either. Also; yes. Two *different* questions, with two *different* groups of likely responders.

Comment: Part of the reason I had trouble explicitly pointing to a reference on that is it took me a good while to research something that they don't spec well. They simply show SATA on the boards; I also had a custom Costco build which is gone, so can't point to that either. But on their order page, it shows SATA 3 (3GB/s), and after researching several other forums, they state that many of the big OEM's are simply not up to speed on enabling SATA 3 (6GB/s) capability.  So as I understand it, you can still use a SATA 3 drive with their SATA 2 capability, but will be bottlenecked at the lower speed.

Comment: Also, agree it's looking more like 2 questions. So I'd rather focus on the dual-boot win7/ubuntu 11 setup best practice.  Since I have a fresh build, I'd like to plan out the best strategy to approach this up front.  1) I could leave win7 on the 1T HDD, and put only ubuntu on the SSD, which I like, but hear people have had boot issues. 2) I could setup up win7/ubuntu dual boot on 1T HDD fairly easy; but am concerned about how easy it will be to pass to smaller 128G SSD.  3) I'm really hoping for someone to chime in with experience who may have done this with a pavillion in the past.

Comment: Okay, I just realised that you referred to the drive, not the mainboard with "I bought the Sata3". [This](http://www.plextor-digital.com/index.php/en/M3/px-1282m3/Page-2.html) appears to answer that question with "compatible with SATA 3Gb/s and 1.5Gb/s" (under the assumption that that is the drive you have).

Comment: You might want to edit the question. =)