# Issues with HP HPE Pavillion Factory HDD clone to new Plextor SSD 128G

Tags: ssd, hp-pavilion

I didn't get too much traction on this earlier thread.
[Best approach to dual boot and clone HP Pavillion](https://superuser.com/questions/406078/best-approach-to-dual-boot-and-clone-hp-pavillion)

But I've run the echo utility and transferred the HDD win7 partition (~50G) to the new SSD drive on SATA port 1.

1. I selected filter on the echo clone option to not transfer the HP recover portion, as it hogged up 17G. But it still transferred an extra partition of 13G of that recovery partition. Not sure why, but I was planning to reformat that part on the SSD to free up the space. Can I just reformat that portion via windows in the SSD drive?
2. I can get the SSD to boot on SATA port 1, by disconnecting the HDD.
3. If I put HDD back, screen goes to BIOS and complains of not finding any device and to install repair disk. I can force HDD select in BIOS and it seems to work (booting back on HDD drive). But will complain if I set SDD as primary drive.

I've read other forums where the user had to reformat the HDD, but I'm trying to avoid that (if possible). I've also read about putting AHCD mode in BIOS.  Lastly, I've tried swapping port orders on physical MB and BIOS boot setup, but no luck.

Comment: Figured it all out for any others stuck here. Works great!  1) deleted recover on SDD, saved it on old HDD. 2) Swap ports to SDD on SATA 0 and HDD on SATA 1. No more Boot issues.

Comment: If you figured it out, post as an answer, make it as accepted, and help the community